# How do i delete n many new lines in bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I am editing a file with sed.

I am using this

```
sed -i 's/^display.*//g'
```

The Problem here is that it not deletes the `\n` newline character.
So if there are many many of affected files it results in a file full of new lines.

So how can I say to sed it should delete the new line too or alternatively use a different bash command to delete all newlines that have more than three newlines in a row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing replacement with `s//g`, do use `d` to delete matching lines:

```
sed -i '/^display/d' file
```

Note that it is not even necessary to indicate the rest of line with `.*`, just `^display` suffices.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello
display is something
and this is another display but
display is here
blabla

$ sed -i '/^display/d' a
$ cat a
hello
and this is another display but
blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you were editing the file, so with `vim` you can do:

```
:g/^display/d
```